# How can I change the indicator list item to an active state when I click on each one for a carousel?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 Carousel, which is generated via javascript. I have successfully been able to create a clickable indicator with text generated from json for each li item in the index. I was able to get the list item to correctly change to the `list-group-item active` state (and change all others back to `list-group-item`) when I cycle through the carousel by clicking on next or previous. But when I click on the indicators, they become active, but I can't get it to switch back to non-active state when clicking each one. Here is my code:

```
  $indicators
    .appendTo($quiz);

  $.each(questions, function(question_index, question) {
    $('<li>')
      .attr('class', 'list-group-item')
      .html(question.prompt)
      .attr('class', question_index ? "" : "list-group-item")
      .click(function() { 
$quiz.carousel($(this).index());
     $(this).toggleClass('list-group-item active');
            })
      .appendTo($indicators);
  });
```

Can anyone please assist? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing `attr('class', ...)` twice?

Comment: @Taplar I suppose it would be my lack of knowledge in this particular situation. Can you please advise?

Comment: To what Taplar said, you set ``.attr`` and then you set it again two lines later with a ternary operator that depends upon whether ``question_index`` has a value. You most likely just need the second ``.attr`` setting if you care about running the check. I'm wondering whether you want to toggle just the ``active`` class on your element. It's hard to tell without seeing more code, but try removing the ``list-group-item`` from your ``.toggleClass``.

Comment: @NotaryClasses What Grant said.  The second call to `attr()` will replace what the first one did, so it is effectively unnecessary.